# Not developing relevant skills at work

Tags: interviewing

I’ve started interviewing elsewhere for the same roles and I am increasingly finding that the skills they are asking for are not in line with the skills I’m developing at my current company.

There are no opportunities to develop these skills since my current org is structured differently.

I’m not sure what to do in this situation.

Should I bend the truth?

Comment: No. Either train on your own time, or seek jobs that don't require those skills, or send an application that emphasizes that you learn new skills quickly. A job listing describes the ideal candidate; they understand that they may not be able to find that person and may hire someone who can become that person. Job listings are notorious for asking for things like five years experience with a tool that is only three years old...

Comment: I have done the training and certified but I have not practically worked in an environment using it and won’t be anytime soon.

Comment: There must be jobs where you get accepted with zero practical experience. That is where all people start. Nobody is born with 5 years experience in X.

Comment: @nvoigt that’s the source of my frustration. I’m ticking every other box but as soon as they hear I don’t have this one skill, it’s a no

Comment: The interviewers will always ask many technical questions to verify if you actually have skills that you list on your resume.

Answer (score 10):

Bend?  How far?  No, lying is not the answer.

You should look for training or resources to upskill or find a job in line with your current skills.

There are plenty of online (often free or cheap) resources to learn some of these new skills to supplement what you already know.

Getting caught in a lie or mis-representation is likely grounds for termination in most companies, you don't want to set yourself up to fail before you even start a job.

Added to address comment:

If you already have training/certification in the skill but no practical experience yet, consider building a personal project to demonstrate your abilities.  It doesn't have to be paid work to be valuable in demonstrating your skill.

Comment: I am already certified in the missing skill but have not had an opportunity to use it. The issue is where every company except mine is using it and I’m finding that I tick all the other boxes with the exception of this one.

Comment: Maybe you can build a personal project to demonstrate mastery of those skills.  It doesn't have to be paid work to count.

Comment: It’s not a technical skill. It’s evidence working within an environment using a certain agile scaling framework. Not particularly hard to pick up in practice since most companies don’t do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

No, I would not lie. That is asking for a whole mess later.

What skills *have* you learned at your current job? I would highlight the learning and growth that you have done to show that you can pick up the skills you're missing on the job. Most companies value employees who can grasp new ideas quickly and teach themselves new concepts.

Answer (score -1):

There's the point that lying is not the answer. Then there's the idea of *fake it till you make it* (and reasons [not to](https://ryanholiday.medium.com/dont-fake-it-till-you-make-it-do-this-instead-117acd2f605f)).

Ultimately the amount by which you decide to stretch the truth is up to you, but the real question is your *reason* for doing so, i.e. what are you trying to achieve here.

If you are trying to land a job where you can learn the more in-demand skill, you probably don't want that skill to be required from day one.

Rather, you might look for a job that offers professional development opportunities that would allow you to build these additional skills alongside with the main work, and (somewhat) independently of it.

So I would suggest reframing the issue: **it's not a matter of the right *job*, but a right *employer***, or an employer that encourages self-development.

So your new job doesn't have to call for new skills. But if the new employer offers better opportunities and culture for learning, it can serve as a springboard to develop the hot new-to-you skills that you can then use to get a job that actually requires them. Good luck!